# Client Application Communication with Application Server

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, xml, client-server, application-server

We're creating a client-server model that communicates with an application server (Java clients, RoR server).

We have a few options for the actual data that is going to be communicated:

1. XML Communication that actually paints the client's screen (a la web-browser)
2. Communicating just data/permissions/etc. through XML (Entire UI is held on client)
3. Combination - Force download the client each time and communicate data/permissions/etc. through XML.

What is the best way of doing this? (Also, we can't use web-browsers since we need to interface with a barcode scanning components in the clients)

Comment: If the only problem is to access a barcode scanner, I would resolve it as a Java Applet, (i.e. accessing the scanner drivers via JNI), and letting all the rest of the system as a web application. I supose there are other requirements that make this as not factible, aren't there?

Comment: One of the clients is an Android phone and the other is a regular workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a thick Java client deployed using Java Web Start.

Comment: Oh.  Both will have to support native call then.  Assuming both client will be Java based, you could definitely use web services or RMI.  Not sure what's the support of Remote Method Interface on the Android SDK though...